# Use HTML and XML files to open a WebView page

Tags: android, html, xml, webview, android-webview

I am trying to open a local HTML file in a WebView which is easy but my problem is that i have to use an XML file which describe the structure of the elements in the HTML file.

When i call a certain API i got 2 files one HTML and one XML, the XML file has a drill down options that describe how content in the HTML will behave.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: so you want to load existing files in webview right ?

Comment: @Purushothaman yes

Comment: @Purushothaman i already know how to load an HTML file in webview but my question is how to use the XML file with it

Comment: Have you parsed XML file?